# How do I prevent javascript written content from being stored in Firefox's wyciwyg cache?

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, firefox

I am working with user data and cannot allow it to be cached.

I am testing with Firefox 4 and a Tomcat 6 server with the cache-control set at no-cache, no-store, private, must-revalidate, max-age=0. I have also set the expires header.

But Firefox is still a generating a wyciwyg (what-you-cache-is-what-you-get) file in it's cache. This might be considered a history mechanism and not a caching mechanism. But it still stores user data.

An example is http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_example.asp.
In Firefox 4.0, the about:cache (specially about:cache?device=disk) page shows the wyciwyg:// file and also the expire date set at "No expiration time". What is worse is that the cache persists after the browser is closed and restarted.

After investigation, for me, the wyciwyg is generated with the contents of a document.write() javascript call.

How do it prevent Firefox from caching this? Ideally without changing the document.write()?

Answer (score 2):

Did you check with Firebug that the cache headers are actually sent to the browser?

But in any case, there's a simple solution to prevent caching: add a timestamp parameter to the request URL.

```
url = '/my/ajax/script?_=' + new Date().getTime();
```

This trick is also used by many JS libraries. If you're using jQuery, it suffices to pass `cache: false` to the AJAX request options.

Comment: Firebug shows the cache headers. This prevents the actual html file from being cached. The part I am concerned about now is the content written by document.write(). 

For example, document.write("personal info"); Would create a wyciwyg:// file with "person info" in it.

Comment: Why do you need to prevent caching this? Is the problem that it *writes* the cache in the first place, or is it that it incorrectly loads stale data from the cache?

Comment: The problem is that it writes the cache. The browser does not load the stale data in my design. But I do not feel comfortable having the personal data persist on the clients local machine browser cache.